# Question about REGEX extracting text beetween

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying in PHP to get something like this:

```
$mail = "fakemail@le.mail.uk.test";
$rep = "le.mail";
```

I tried like this:

```
function test($mail) {
  $pattern = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/';
  preg_match($pattern, $mail, $matches);
  echo $matches[2] . "\n";
}
test("fakemail@le.mail.uk");

// result = le.mail
```

but if i have another `.` in my mail it's broken

```
function test($mail) {
  $pattern = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/';
  preg_match($pattern, $mail, $matches);
  echo $matches[2] . "\n";
}
test("fakemail@le.mail.uk.test.test");

// result = le.mail.uk.test.test.test
// whatIwant = le.mail
```

or I just want all character between `@` and until the next `.`.
I think I have to do a loop with an `if` but I'm not sure if it's possible
with only regex.

Comment: You'll need to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Your question does not explain well what you're expecting to get from this function.

Comment: If You only need string between first `@` and `.`, You can use `/@([^.]*)/` and Your result is in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: ohh yep sorry my bad i will correct that ^^'

Comment: Okay, so are you saying that "le.mail" is the _desired_ result from "fakemail@le.mail.uk"?  Is so, that doesn't match up with your statement "i just want all character between @ and the first '.'"

Comment: miken32 : i just want all character beetwen @ and the first "."  no matter how many "." there is after like for this email@test.com.robot i just want "test.com" or if i have email@test.fr.uk.robot i just want "test.fr" sorry if i'm not really good to explain it, i'm still learning english :/

Comment: yep that's right Patrick Q, i don't know how to say it correctly sorry =x

Comment: Why not just use `preg_match('~@\K[^.]+~', $s, $m)` if *i just want all character beetwen @ and until the next "."* is true? If you plan to match from `@` till the `.` that is followed with TLD, you will need a list of TLDs.

Comment: So, you want `preg_match('~@\K[^.]+\.[^.]+~', $s, $m)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2XLtZ8/2/codegen?language=php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A php way without `REGEX`, using `implode()` and `explode()`

```
<?php
$sep = '.';
$str1 = 'email@test.com.robot';
$str2 = 'email@test.fr.uk.robot';
$get1 = explode($sep,explode('@',$str1)[1]);
$get2 = explode($sep,explode('@',$str2)[1]);
echo implode($sep,[$get1[0],$get1[1]]);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo implode($sep,[$get2[0],$get2[1]]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
test.com 
test.fr
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/hJu52

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will try to understand all of it ^^

Comment: Glad it helps u somehow, best of luck :)